# Any libraries of reading & writing binary file formats (PE & ELF)?

Tags: c, binary, elf, portable-executable

HellO,

I want to write a binary file format viewer for windows which can operate on both PE & ELF files. Similar to the ones already there:

- PE Explorer http://www.pe-explorer.com/
- PE VIew:  http://www.magma.ca/~wjr/
- PEBrowse Professional http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-file-viewer.html

I've reasons why I want to write "yet another binary viewer".

Are there any C libraries for reading PE & ELF file formats? I've downloaded Gnu binutils's source code and figured out that it uses [Binary File Descriptor Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) which claims to support approximately 50 file formats for some 25 processor architectures. I'm not sure if it implements the complete PE specifications because its basically a library for Linux where PE format is rarely used. Moreover, the library source code seems to be little complex and redundant for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about `C`, but you might get your inspiration from [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/), which is a `python` library.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [PeLib](http://www.pelib.com). It can't handle ELF but at least it could help handle the PE format for you.